# How can I customize the look of the h1,h2,h3, tag format of the CKEditor editor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

How can I customize the look of the h1,h2,h3, tag fprmat of the CKEditor so that I can make them match my local CSS style of h1,h2,h3,etc .. The CSS file I use is boostrap.css Below is the config.js of the ckeditor

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2003-2011, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
*/

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

    config.LinkUpload = false;
    config.LinkBrowser = false;

    config.skin = 'kama';

    config.Format   = 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;address;div' ;
    config.FontName = 'Arial;Comic Sans MS;Courier New;Tahoma;Times New Roman;Verdana' ;
    config.FontSize = 'smaller;larger;xx-small;x-small;small;medium;large;x-large;xx-large' ;

    config.toolbar_Testimonial = [
                                    ['Bold','Italic','Underline','RemoveFormat']
                                 ];

    config.toolbar_KarlBell =  [
                                ['Source','DocProps','-','Save','NewPage','Preview','-','Templates'], 
                                ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteWord','-','Print','SpellCheck'],
                                ['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
                                ['Bold','Italic','Underline','StrikeThrough','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
                                ['OrderedList','UnorderedList','-','Outdent','Indent'],
                                ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyFull'],
                                ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
                                ['Image','Flash','Table','Rule','Smiley','SpecialChar'],
                                ['Form','Checkbox','Radio','TextField','Textarea','Select','Button','ImageButton','HiddenField'],
                                '/',
                                ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize'],
                                ['TextColor','BGColor']
                            ] ; 
    config.toolbar_KarlBell = [
                                    ['Format','Bold','Italic','Underline','BulletedList','NumberedList','Link']
                                 ];                        

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fast and dirty way is to include your css in the ckeditor css:

you `/ckeditor/content.css` should start with:

```
@import "/css/boostrap.css"; /*your site css*/

...
```

Note that the other content in the file will override some of your css declaration so remove them accordingly

`content.css` is what you need for customizing how ckeditor show its content during editing.

Comment: In what file should that be included ??

Comment: @user3267381 /ckeditor/content.css Inside the ckeditor folder there are a content.css file

Comment: Oh I see .. so I can just include the bootstrap CSS data in the content.css file ?

Comment: @user3267381 yes, in the first line

Comment: it's working .. but I have another quick question .. I have to work with two CSS files that sometimes will be needed depending on a situation .. how would I handle that ?

Comment: ..how I can include css styles in the code above for h1, h2, or p html tags?

Comment: @user3267381 you can copy only the relevant part of your boostrap.css to content.css